# How can I add and manipulate existing GET variables of the current url in php?

Tags: php, url, get

Hi I have URLs like this...

```
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars&loc=Ludhiana
```

Now i want to sort all my results on basis of price, model and visits. SO i use

```
$sort="id";
    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
        if($_GET['sort']=='P-ASC'){ $sort = "price ASC"; }
        elseif($_GET['sort']=='P-DESC'){ $sort = "price DESC"; }
        elseif($_GET['sort']=='R-ASC'){ $sort = "model ASC"; }
        elseif($_GET['sort']=='R-DESC'){ $sort = "model DESC"; }
        elseif($_GET['sort']=='V-ASC'){ $sort = "visits ASC"; }
        elseif($_GET['sort']=='V-DESC'){ $sort = "visits DESC"; }
    }
```

Now i want to add sort variable at the end of url to sort results. e.g.

```
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars&sort='**ANYVALUE**'
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars&loc=Ludhiana&sort='**ANYVALUE**'
```

And on href i am using which is working absolutely fine for me so far...

```
<a href="?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&sort='**Anyvalue**'"
```

Problem exists when i try to manipulate sort value e.g. I have two href

```
<a href="?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&sort='P-ASC'"
<a href="?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&sort='P-DESC'"
```

When i go to first url it works fine and when i go to second url after using first one then the URL add another sort variable in URL result in TWO sort variables in URL. What i want is

1. To check if any of these GET variable exists or not ?
2. If it exists then manipulate value of those variables ?
3. And if doesn't exist then add new get variable to URL.

Answer (score 0):

`http_build_query($_GET + ['sort' => 'anyvalue'])`

should work

**EDIT**

plus sign for arrays do this

```
$a = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3];
$b = ['a' => 4, 'd' => 5];
$res = $a + $b;
```

It adds keys to array `$a` from `$b` that are not present in `$a`

This is `$res` variable:

```
array(4) {
  'a' =>
  int(1)
  'b' =>
  int(2)
  'c' =>
  int(3)
  'd' =>
  int(5)
}
```

And `http_build_query` function builds a query string from array.
so `http_build_query($res)` will be:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=5
```

In your case you can use it like this:

```
<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET + ['sort' => '**AnyValue**']); ?>">link</a>
```

Comment: Hi @Petr I am new to PHP and using this concept for the very first time. Can you please add little more detail on how to use it ?? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Petr. But it gives a PHP error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' "

Comment: which PHP version do you use?

Comment: Its WAMP SERVER 2.2

Comment: just replace `['sort' => '**AnyValue**']` with `array('sort' => '**AnyValue**')`

Comment: And php version is 5.3.13.

Comment: I used "<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] + array('sort' => 'P-ASC')); ?>">Link</a>". It is removing that error but query has been stopped here.

Comment: what do you mean query has been stopped here?

Comment: oh, my bad. I'm sorry. Forget that QUERY_STRING is actually string :D try this: `http_build_query($_GET + array('sort' => 'abcd'));`

Comment: Its working sir but problem is in this code also...Once the url load with a sort value it doesn't change value of sort field on clicking another link. e.g. if URL is ?sort=P-ASC then when i click on link that contain ?sort=P-DESC It doesn;t change sort value...

Comment: you want replace the sort value with new-one? su use array_merge instead of adding arrays `http_build_query(array_merge($GET, array('sort' => 'value'));`

Comment: `http_build_query(array_merge($GET, array('sort' => isset($_GET['sort']) ? 'value' : NULL);`

Comment: if there is no sort query paramater, it does not add it

Comment: yeah....if there is a sort parameter in query then its working....Is there any way to do this ??

Comment: can you please be more specific, what do you want? I'm getting lost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139598/discussion-between-ashish-and-petr-jirous).